# Select a different image depending on a variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to select a different image depending on the `click.id` so I have to give id to indicate the image. I'm doing it like this:

```js
const imgChange = document.querySelector('.eyeImage img');
const eyeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.icons .fa-eye');

eyeBtn.forEach((click) => {
  click.addEventListener('click', () => {
    eyeImage.classList.remove('active');
    if (click.id === 'product-1') {
      imgChange.src = 'images/product-1.png';
    } else if (click.id === 'product-2') {
      imgChange.src = 'images/product-2.png';
    } else if (click.id === 'product-3') {
      imgChange.src = 'images/product-3.png';
    }
  });
});
```

Is there any proper way to achieve it?

Comment: If the `id` always maps directly to the image name then just use it to construct the src `imgChange.src = \`images/${click.id}.png\`;` (here using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))

Comment: yes I understood but i am asking why we have to give id in each buttons lets suppose i have 50 buttons and 50 image so in order to show them I have to put if else condition like this ? @pilchard

Comment: You don't have to give them all ids and my comment avoids any `if...else` by directly using the id to construct a src string. You could use a data attribute if you'd prefer, but at some point there has to be a logical mapping between button and image, either through an explicit attribute like an id or an implicit attribute like the position of an element in an array or in reference to its parent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use expressions on a string using ` instead of ':

```
const imgChange = document.querySelector('.eyeImage img');
const eyeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.icons .fa-eye');

eyeBtn.forEach((click) => {
  click.addEventListener('click', () => {
    eyeImage.classList.remove('active');
    imgChange.src = `images/product-${click.id}.png`;
  });
});
```

Example with a `for`:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) console.log(`images/product-${i}`);
```